# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid3, ruby-2.1

Trying to install mongoid 3.1.6 in rails 4.1

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:

```
mongoid (~> 3.1.6) ruby depends on
  activemodel (~> 3.2) ruby

rails (= 4.1.0) ruby depends on
  activerecord (= 4.1.0) ruby depends on
    activemodel (4.1.0)
```

It works fine when mongoid is downgraded to 1.0.6 but i need to use mongoid 3.1.6 in rails 4.1.
Is there any solution to solve this problemt?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to use a 4.x version of mongoid, which uses `activemodel >= 4.0.0`.  Here's the latest:

```
gem 'mongoid', '~> 4.0.0'
```

Comment: It works fine thank you, but now i have this error while starting rails server 
uninitialized constant Sprockets::Rails::VERSION (NameError)

Comment: Are you upgrading an existing app from Rails 3.2.x to 4?  Or, starting from scratch?  I think this is another gem dependency issue somewhere.

Comment: starting a new application from scratch, using ruby 2.1.1, rails 4.1

Comment: Small update on this - authors already released version 4.0.0 of Mongoid gem, for more details see https://rubygems.org/gems/mongoid